# How to find the sum of multiple columns for each individual record in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking to find the sum of the values of multiple columns in my database. This is for a Fantasy Basketball app that provides statistical analysis of all the players in a Fantasy League. I am trying to add together 7 columns for each record in the DB. I am not sure whether it would be better to use the ActiveRecord querying methods or to use an actual SQL query. Here is the method that I was attempting to use within the SeasonPlayer model:

```
   def self.find_player_value_totals
     player_values = []
     query = <<-SQL
               SELECT id,( free_throw_value + three_pointer_value + 
               rebounds_value + assists_value + steals_value + 
               blocks_value + points_value )
               AS value_total
               FROM season_players
             SQL
     totals = find_by_sql(query)

     totals.each do |total|
       player_values << total.value_total
     end
  end
```

Using this query in my MySQL DB I can find the totals without any issues:

```
select id,( free_throw_value + three_pointer_value + rebounds_value + assists_value + steals_value + blocks_value + points_value ) AS value_total FROM season_players
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am not a Rails expert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question. But I think this is what you want to implement:

```
class SeasonPlayers
  # assuming that you only want to aggregate from one player
  def find_player_value_totals
    [free_throw_val, three_pointer_val, rebound_val, assist_val, steals_val, blocks_val, points_val].sum
  end
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your response @pauloancheta! I am looking to aggregate the totals for each player. I am not sure how to iterate through multiple arrays at the same time.